# Can I pin an item inside RecyclerView to the centre while scaling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items in a `RecyclerView`, which is scalable when pinching, and it currently scales the items fine, with the first list item staying when it is (the far left one).

What I'm looking to do is to keep the centre item pinned in the centre while I scale. I'm hoping that `RecyclerView` makes this easy for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If item is focused, LinearLayoutManager will preserve its position when layout occurs. (L-preview does not do this but L release will have it). This may not be enough for you if you want to keep item's center stable because LLM will keep the items reference point stable. (e.g. reference point is the top pixel of the item if layout is vertical and reverseLayout is false).

As a workaround, you can call LLM#scrollToPositionWithOffset with proper values each time you resize the View.

Comment: `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` works perfectly for now - thank you!

Comment: yigit could you please take a look at [this somewhat related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909654/recyclerview-doesnt-scale-with-its-item). I guess if you can't help then nobody could, appreciate it