# RecyclerView doesn't scale with its item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, scale

Here's [github rep](https://github.com/kidwon24/ScalableRecyclerViewItem) example of the issue and the `RecyclerView` [adapter](https://github.com/kidwon24/ScalableRecyclerViewItem/blob/master/app/src/main/java/mom/example/itemlist/adapters/ItemListRecycleViewAdapter.kt) for your convenience.

I am scaling `RecyclerView` item on click

```
imageView.setOnClickListener {
    val pivotType = Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF
    val scaleAnime = ScaleAnimation(1f,2f,1f,2f,
            pivotType, 0.5f, pivotType, 0.5f )

    scaleAnime.duration = 400
    scaleAnime.fillAfter = true
    ViewCompat.setElevation(it,1f)
    it.startAnimation(scaleAnime)
}
```

However, I'm struggling with the following issues:

- The RecyclerView itself doesn't react to the clicked item new size although it's height is `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

  I might use

  ```
  android:clipChildren="false"
  android:clipToPadding="false"
  ```

  and avoid the cutting of the view but that would reveal the overflow items which isn't desired option as well so I'm struggling to find a way for the `RecyclerView` to grow with the scale, too.
- The scaled item overlaps over it's neighbor items instead of pushing them away

I have tried changing the height of the RV but it grows downward only compare to scale effect which grows top and bottom.

Anybody who has idea how to resolve these issues please share or even suggest an alternative.

Comment: don't link to code hosted externally. Instead, create a MVCE for us

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared the layouts of your `RecyclerView` and the list items. You called for an alternative if possible. Hence I suggest you might take a look at expandable `RecyclerView` where each item will expand on clicking on them.

Here's a [nice library](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) for creating the expandable `RecyclerView` that you want.

You might consider looking into [this one](https://github.com/hendraanggrian/recyclerview-expandable) as well. The implementations are simple.

Comment: I think I did [look here](https://github.com/kidwon24/ScalableRecyclerViewItem/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout). Thank you for the links but I am looking to scale an item not to expand